# Is the CPU Usage Wrong in the Diagnostics Display (Visual Studio)? Seems to Display Less Thread Usage than I Counted

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, parallel.foreach

I need maximum performance for my project, but the diagnostics display never indicates more than 5-10% processor usage. That is in spite of parallelizing the work and allocating all available cores. So I made a demonstrator project to isolate the issue. The project uses Parallel.ForEach on a list with 88,779 elements.

[image: Screenshot shows the CPU utilization in the diagnostics panel, and also my count of distinct threads used]

I specifically designed my demonstrator project to put a big demand on the system, yet run fast enough to be convenient. A list of 88K elements surely justifies *using all 20* of my available cores, yet the diagnostics display suggests an actual usage of only 5-10%. (Refer to my screen shot above - the graph looks like only a few cores are used)

I suspected the diagnostic display might be wrong, so I wrote some code to count the distinct thread IDs allocated inside my loop. That count seems to conflict with Visual Studio's display. To wit, I counted 22 distinct threads being allocated inside the parallel loop, which is 110% usage by my arithmetic. Either my thread count is wrong, or else the diagnostics display is wrong (or misleading).

### Parallel Loop Iterating a List of 88,799 Elements Given 20 Cores

```
ParallelOptions opts = new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = NumProcessorsToUse };
ConcurrentBag<int> threadIDs = new();
var tmr = new Stopwatch();
tmr.Start();
//lastNames has almost 89k names, I think all 20 cores should be used:
Parallel.ForEach(lastNames, opts, lName => {
    DoWork(lName, allWords, firstNames);
    threadIDs.Add(Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId);
});
tmr.Stop();
grdResults.ItemsSource = _Results;

var threadCount = threadIDs.Distinct().Count();
var msg = $"Elapsed time: {tmr.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000} seconds; max thread count: {threadCount}"; 
MessageBox.Show(msg, "Processing Complete", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

| My Theory | Action | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Running in debug mode reserves some cores for Visual Studio | I ran the exe outside of Visual Studio, i.e. not in debug mode | Elapsed time was *roughly the same* as debug mode. Consequently, I don't think a significant amount of available CPU is being stolen by Visual Studio |
| Somehow only 4 cores are allocated | I timed it after explicitly assigning only 4 cores | Run is now *roughly 8 seconds*, i.e. 33% slower. That indicates that more than 4 cores were used when I told it to use 20 |
| Contention between the threads causes execution to wait | Note that I store the results (i.e. email names) in a ConcurrentBag. This is the only code that writes, the rest of the code reads from memory. I listed my method DoWork below | To verify, I commented out the code to save each result. The upshot: it ran in 4 seconds (instead of 6, so 33% faster) but the *diagnostic display of CPU utilization remained the same* |
| My stopwatch or thread counting interferes | I ran the code without any of that | The code runs in the same amount of time |

### My Method DoWork

```
private void DoWork(string lName, HashSet<string> allWords, List<string> firstNames) {
    foreach (var fName in firstNames) {
        if (fName.Length > 1 && lName.Length > 2) {
            var emName = fName[..2] + lName[..3];
            //Allwords is a Hashset<string>
            if (allWords.Contains(emName)) {
                var addMe = new Email { EmailName = emName, First = fName, Last = lName };
                //The only code that writes to memory:
                _Results.Add(addMe);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Summary

I built a demonstrator project that I thought would use all 20 cores, but the diagnostics display tells me only a small amount of my processing power is being used. That disagrees with the thread allocation count I measured.

I suspect the display is wrong in Visual Studio - is my suspicion correct? Do I need to process an even bigger list before .NET will allocate more processors? If .NET won't allocate more processors, is there anything I can do to speed things up?

If the consensus is that the diagnostics display is wrong, I'll submit a suggestion to Microsoft asking them to take a look.

Comment: Amdahl's law at work, easily visible from the blur of gen#1 collections.  You'd need serverGC to make this more effective.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/runtime-config/garbage-collector#flavors-of-garbage-collection

Comment: Hello Hans, I don't see how Amdahl's Law will apply here. The work being done - iterating the list - can completely be split into 20 parts that do not interfere with each other. There should be no contention between each chunk of work. Note that I tested it without writing any results to memory and got roughly the same results, so contention doesn't apply. Also, I don't understand how garbage collection should affect the number of threads displayed in the diagnostics. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: What type is _Results? Interested in reproducing.

Comment: And what type is Email?

Comment: Hello David - thankyou for your interest. _Results is ConcurrentBag<Email>. Email is a class with 3 string properties (first/last/email). I can give you the code if you have a means for me to share it with you.

Comment: Diagnostic displays in Visual Studio may not accurately reflect actual CPU core usage. You can check CPU usage in Windows Task Manager: this will give you an idea if all CPU cores are being used.

Comment: Hi GetValue - I examined the CPU utilization in Task Manager while running my program and it indicated about 80% CPU utilization, so that supports your point of view.

Comment: @ActualRandy Hi, I posted my comment as an answer. You can mark it so that you can help more people

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I work at Microsoft and my team owns the Diagnostics Tools window in Visual Studio. We are tracking this question with the following [feedback ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/CPU-Utilization-Display-Appears-to-be-Wr/10342698)

My hunch here is that the CPU graph is over estimating debugging overhead resulting in low usage. When running under the debugger we attempt to capture when the debugger is inside the debugee doing work and subtract that from both the overall time and the CPU profile. Without this when the debugger is doing work in the user process you would get spikes such as entering break state or throwing exceptions. We try to remove this "debugger overhead" to give better insight into what the "user code" profile is, though there are cases where this doesn't always work.

To verify if this is the case and to get accurate performance numbers you can use the same CPU Usage tool in the Performance Profiler (Alt+F2) with the application built in release mode. This will give you the most accurate representation of the performance of the code with all compiler optimizations.

Comment: Hi Nik - I saw your request for additional info and added a couple screenshots which look the same as the problematic CPU graph, i.e., also not accurate. I also attached my code and data files, though I added a forgotten one later. That means you will need to revise the path in code, for that last file, to point to a location on your machine.

Comment: Also, I accidentally ran the Performance Profiler in debug mode when I made my screen shot and submitted it. I realized my mistake and then profiled it in *release mode*, but results were the same.